# toLocaleString, Percentages, and Firefox 38

Tags: javascript, localization, floating-point

I'm trying to format a percentage to have three significant figures. I'd like a fairly small percentage, something like 1075 / 107175175, to show up as 0.0001%.

```
var x = 1075 / 107175175;
console.log(x.toLocaleString('en-us', {
    style: 'percent', minimumSignificantDigits: 1
}));
```

What I'm getting instead is '0.00100303078581397%.' Is this an issue with how floating point numbers are implemented in Javascript or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using maximumSignificantDigits: 1?

```
console.log(x.toLocaleString('en-us', {
    style: 'percent', maximumSignificantDigits: 1
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a small logical mistake, `minimumSignificantDigits` means show at least N numbers, while in your case i think you want to use `maximumSignificantDigits` which means show maximun 1 significant digit.